# Start a screensaver when explorer is not the shell

Tags: c#, screensaver, shellexecute

I'm running my own kiosk application as the shell (replacing HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows NT/winlogon/shell).

The application needs to be able to turn off the monitor and I was using Process.Start("scrnsave.scr") to do this. It works on my dev machine but not when the shell is replaced.

It's clearly because the UseShellExecute is set to true, but when I set it to false I can't get the screensaver to run. Using explorer.exe as the command and scrnsave.scr as the argument just causes an explorer window to open.

Is there a switch I can pass to explorer to get it to run the screensaver or is there another way to achieve the same thing?

Thanks.

Comment: Turn the monitor *off* with a screen saver?  Google SC_MONITORPOWER.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start the screen saver by sending a windows message to the system.

```
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_SCREENSAVE, 0)
```

You will need the following definitions

```
static readonly IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffff);
static readonly IntPtr SC_SCREENSAVE = new IntPtr(0xf140);
const uint WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;

[DllImport("User32",SetLastError=true)]
extern static int SendMessage(
  IntPtr hWnd,
  uint Msg,
  IntPtr wParam,
  IntPtr lParam);
```

Which you can then use as follows

```
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_SCREENSAVE, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it certainly kicks off the screensaver. There doesn't seem to be an API call to set the screensaver to the blank one by default though... guess it'll have to just be part of our build process.